# Make multiple histograms for each column in matrix

Tags: matlab

I would like to loop through each column in a 306X20 matrix, with NaN values filling in the empty spaces, and I would like to create a histogram for each row (finish with 20 histograms).  What would be the best way to do this?  The pseudocode that I would like to implement:

```
For i = 1:(number of columns)
     % Loop through each column to generate a different histogram with the same
     % x and y labels and title
     % hist(data, 20)
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want a separate figure for each histogram. This can be achieved easily with a for-loop and the `figure`-statement to open a new figure in each iteration. In Matlab version R2014b and above, use the `histogram`-function to plot the histogram, in versions below R2014b use `hist` instead (`hist` still works in R2014b and above). Both functions ignore `NaN`-values in the dataset.

```
% generate random data with NaN-values
x = randn(306,20);
a = randi(5,[306,20]);
x(a==3) = NaN;

% plot the histograms
for i = 1:size(x,2)
    figure;
    histogram(x(:,i)) % before R2014b use "hist" instead
    title(['Histogram of row ',num2str(i)]);
    xlabel('Bins');
    ylabel('Frequency');
end
```

*This gives the following result for the last row:*
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [`unique`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`bsxfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). The result will be the cell arrays `values` that contains the unique values and `count` that contains occurrences of those values.

```
A= [1 2 5; 1 7 NaN]; % // Test data

% // Convert it to a cell array so that we can apply a function to each row
B=mat2cell(A, [size(A,1)] ,[ones(size(A,2),1).']);

% // Find the unique values
[values,ia,indvalues]=cellfun(@unique,B,'UniformOutput',false);

% // Count the unique occurrencies.
count = cellfun(@(M) sum( bsxfun(@eq, M, unique(M)') )', B, 'UniformOutput',false);


>> values{1}

ans =

 1

>> count{1}

ans =

     2
```